# Power BI Gantt Chart

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, deneb

Can someone enlighten me on how to create a visual like this? Visual that show how long the business proposal has been and if they are still in negotiating phase or closing deals already.

I tried searching all over the internet for a week now, but until now I can't find any answer. Hope someone higher knowledge than me help me. Thank you in Advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Deneb and the VL template here to create this chart in PowerBI.

[image]

https://deneb-viz.github.io/

https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/bar_gantt.html

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rBU7Xp1xYA

I have PBI on my work laptop, but I am not on that machine now. I don't have PBI installed on my personal laptop, so I can't try it out right now.